# iframe youtube video from youtube is not working on device

Tags: html, cordova, iframe, youtube

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

i have built andriod an app on intel xdk cordova app designer and used iframe for my videos from youtube now its is running quite good on emulator buton device it just show my videos thumbnails and on clicking does nothing and for vevo videos it shows a warning that it is restricted play on youtube.probably i used most of the plugins of cordova. my CSP is following

help me ...